# android: access local network share

Tags: android

I was wondering, is there any way to get a file/directory listing from a local network share?

Iam trying to make an app that shows an overview of all the movies or music on my NAS.

Martijn Lenderink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find a library that understands SMB/CIFS. [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) is known to work but I haven't used it myself. If you want to try it, most major Android file manager apps support this.